# What's the time complexity of this algorithm for solving an interview question?

Tags: python, algorithm, dictionary

The [problem](https://leetcode.com/discuss/interview-question/924141/google-phone-screen-new-grad) goes as follows:

> You have a stream of RPC requests coming in which is being logged. Each log entry is of the form
> `{rpc_id, timestamp, type (start or end)}`. Given a timeout value `T`, you need to
> figure out at the earliest possible time if any requests have timed out.

```
E.g.:
id - time - type
0 - 0 - Start
1 - 1 - Start
0 - 2 - End
2 - 6 - Start
1 - 7 - End
Timeout = 3
Answer: {1, 6} ( figured out id 1 had timed out at time 6 )
```

The linked page contains some `O(n)` solutions using a doubly linked list and a hashmap. Since a Python dict preserves the insertion order, I think it's possible to use it as the only data structure:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass


@dataclass(frozen=True, slots=True)
class LogEntry:
    rpc_id: int
    timestamp: int
    action: str


class LogProcessor:
    def __init__(self, timeout: int):
        self.entries = {}
        self.timeout = timeout

    def process_log_entry(self, entry: LogEntry) -> list[LogEntry]:
        if entry.action == 'Start':
            self.entries[entry.rpc_id] = entry
        elif entry.rpc_id in self.entries and entry.timestamp - self.entries[entry.rpc_id].timestamp <= self.timeout:
            del self.entries[entry.rpc_id]

        timed_out = []

        for k, v in self.entries.items():
            if entry.timestamp - v.timestamp <= self.timeout:
                break
            timed_out.append(v)

        for e in timed_out:
            del self.entries[e.rpc_id]

        return timed_out


log_processor = LogProcessor(timeout=3)

assert log_processor.process_log_entry(LogEntry(1, 0, 'Start')) == []
assert log_processor.process_log_entry(LogEntry(2, 1, 'Start')) == []
assert log_processor.process_log_entry(LogEntry(1, 2, 'End')) == []
assert log_processor.process_log_entry(LogEntry(3, 6, 'Start')) == [LogEntry(2, 1, 'Start')]
```

Is the time complexity of this algorithm still `O(n)`?

Comment: There should be a super simple way to test that: just test it. Does it behave O(n)?

Comment: IIUC, `process_log_entry` is called on every log entry, right? If so, the loop over `entries.items()` can create a worst case of `O(n^2)`. Intuitively, I would lean toward a [`heapq`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/heapq.html) solution.

Comment: @PierreD The second loop affects just some amount of entries, which are subsequently removed from the dict, so I'm not sure the time complexity will end up being `O(n^2)`.

Comment: You can easily create a `O(n^2)` scenario with your code: a log entry generator that always emits `(i, i, 'Start')` for `i in range(n)` and `timeout = n`. For this reason, I would use a `heapq` with the first element always the minimum time of timeout (i.e. `t + timeout` and use min heapq).

Comment: @PierreD You're missing the `break` statement in that `for`. It will break the loop on the first iteration, thus `O(n)`.

Comment: Fair. But is there a guarantee in the problem statement that `timestamp` is monotonic increasing? I don't see that explicitly stated.

Comment: I believe that's the case.

Comment: Oh, but in that case the problem is trivial. And, in that case, yes, your code is `O(n)`: any entry in the dict is either slated for deletion or causes a break of that for loop. In other words, there is no situation where an item beyond the first entry in the dict would be examined more than once overall.

Comment: Other ways the stream can be corrupted, besides times (even slightly) out of order: repeated `rpc_id` with multiple starts, multiple stops, or a mix. One has to think and define what the desired behavior is. One could enforce "correctness", e.g. assert Stop follows an existing Start for that id, and Start belong to an id not currently in the dict. For example, inserting a new start for an existing id will make your dict out of order wrt timestamps.

Comment: @PierreD Every problem is "trivial" when you see a simple working solution ;)